# Qt5 make a copy of ini file(QSettings) to build folder using CMake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I'm Qt5 beginner.

I saved two `.ini` file with `QSettings` for two different layout of toolbars and dockwidgets.

`coolUI.ini` and `fantacyUI.ini`

I move them to my project folder and want to copy them to the build/release folder when building with CMake.

And then I can reset to one of them anytime in my app.

If any information is needed, please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `coolUI.ini` file is in a project directory/subdirectory that contains a `CMakeLists.txt` file you may try to use

```
file(COPY_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/coolUI.ini ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/coolUI.ini)
```

or

```
file(COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/coolUI.ini DESTINATION ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})
```

or

```
configure_file(coolUI.ini ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/coolUI.ini COPYONLY)
```

command from that CMakeLists.txt file to achieve that. Otherwise you need to adapt the input and output paths. `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` is the folder where your executable will be created into.